# Need help on Rod Cutting with Memoization

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I had implelmented the rod cutting using memoization technique in java and here is the code that i have come up so far:

```
public class RodCutMemo {
public static int [] memo;
public static void main(String args [])
{    int []  prices = {0,2,3,5,8,6,4,9,10,12,15,16,17,18,20,22,31,50} ;
     int n=5;
     memo = new int [n+1]; 
     for(int i =1;i<=n;i++)
     {   memo[i]=-9999;}
     System.out.println(maxProfitRodCutMemo(prices ,n));
}
public static int maxProfitRodCutMemo(int [] prices,int n)
{       if(memo[n]>=0)
        {
        return memo[n];}
    //else if(n==0)
    //{
     // return 0;
    //}
    else
    {   int q = -9999;
        for(int i =1;i<=n;i++)
        {q=Math.max(q,prices[i]+maxProfitRodCutMemo(prices, n-i) );}
        return q;}}}
```

I have two questions here...

Q1)I have commented out one of the base conditions..`if(n==0)`.Is that required in code.Am i missing some corner case without that??

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

The simple answer to your question comes out when you consider i=n(in the for loop in the function maxProfitRodCutMemo), which will lead to calling of maxProfitRodCutMemo(int [] prices,0), which wont give you a correct result
according to your code (as you dont have any condition to check it)..

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the right answer as ,when  `maxProfitRodCutMemo(int [] prices,0),` is called ,it will be handled by `if(memo[n]>=0)`.Here `memo[0] is equal to 0`

Comment: Well, Not familiar with java (as you had no tags as java), well that is the only possibility when you might need the base case of n==0...